# Eclipse Plugin Class not found exception

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, classnotfoundexception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64
    at org.com.strobe.actions.validation.valid_token(validation.java:18)
    at org.com.strobe.actions.project_check.check_database(project_check.java:88)
    at org.com.strobe.actions.project_check.check(project_check.java:30)
    at org.com.strobe.actions.ToolbarAction.run(ToolbarAction.[
```

---

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FxHz.png)java:131)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:247)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:219)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$5(ActionContributionItem.java:436)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 cannot be found by org.com.Strobe_1.0.0
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:484)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 34 more

Comment: What is it? Voted for closing.

Comment: Have you included all those jars in the `build.properties`? If they aren't listed there they won't be included in the built plug-in.

Comment: I include in build properties too..@greg-449

bin.includes = plugin.xml,\ html/,\
icons/,\
intro/,\
testToc.xml,\
toc.xml,\
contexts.xml,\
META-INF/,\
build.properties,\
.project,\
public.pem,\
XML/,\
.,\
.classpath,\
               bin/,\
               utility.pem,\
               lib/commons-codec-1.11.jar,\
               lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar,\
               lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar,\
               lib/commons-io-2.4.jar